# Updating header record or adding line record in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a view that displays `HeaderModel` details. Under this is displays `LineModel`s associated with this header.

Some of the `LineModel` fields are required.

My problem is when it comes to updating the header the `ModelState.IsValid` is false, because some of the fields that a new `LineModel` would require are not filled in.

How can I get around this and allow updating the header and adding lines in one view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well you can use the bind exclude:

```
public ActionResult Update([Bind(Exclude = "LineModelNameProperty")]HeaderModel model){

}
```